# How to show a specific Bootstrap tab pane based on the URL hashtag?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I have this default markup for Bootstrap toggable tabs.

How to open a specific tab pane (Messages in this example) if my url has its ID as hashtag?

i.e.: www.mydomain.com/my-tabbed-page#messages

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.nav-tabs').length > 0) { // if .nav-tabs exists
        var hashtag = window.location.hash;
        if (hashtag!='') {
            $('.nav-tabs > li').removeClass('active');
            $('.nav-tabs > li > a[href="'+hashtag+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
            $('.tab-content > div').removeClass('active');
            $(hashtag).addClass('active');
        }
    }

});
```